# How to create a overlay gradient background?

Tags: html, css, web

I've been looking for some answers to solve that issue I've found while developing a webpage. I'm trying to create a overlay gradient background like these examples I found on the web:

http://meridianthemes-demo.net/the-traveler/

http://demo.themeruby.com/innovation_personal/

**My code currently looks like this:**

```css
.image-bg{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    background: url('../images/background.jpg') center center no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    &:before {
        content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom right, #e2dce1, #e8d5e4);
  opacity: .8;

    }
}
```

```html
<body class="image-bg">
    <div class="container" id="main">

        <div class="logo">
            <h1>Background Overlay Image</h1>
        </div> <!-- ./ logo -->

    </div> <!-- ./Container -->
```

...

**Any ideas of how to change that code to something similar to the themes I've mentioned above?**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: right click the background > Inspect Element. You can find out what they did. That's probably going to teach you more than having the solution hand-fed to you... IMHO.

Comment: Let's assume that when we come to stack overflow we may have done plenty of research. So yes, I've done that before and couldn't really grasp the right solution.

Comment: Your example code demonstrated an informed attempt, which can't be said for half the new threads on SO. Not sure why he was putting you down.

Comment: My intent was not to put anyone down, merely to out the possibility of self help. I can't assume you've done research, as few new posters do any. If you want people to know you've done research, demonstrate it. For instance, the first link shows a much different technique than your example. Tell us what problems you had with what you saw there. See [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a gradient of solid colors with opacity on the element, you can create a gradient with `rgba` (red/green/blue/alpha) colors, where one side of the gradient can be semi-transparent while the other is opaque.

I modified your code to show how to pull this off.

Also, you had nesting in your CSS (`&:before`) which doesn't work in native CSS - only a preprocessor like SCSS. I formatted it to work below.

```css
.image-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/NRdrfQw.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}

.image-bg::before {
    content: '';
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2), rgba(255, 255, 255, 1));
    z-index: -1;
  }

  .container {
    height: 800px;
  }
```

```html
<body class="image-bg">
  <div class="container" id="main">
    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Background Overlay Image</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ logo -->
  </div>
  <!-- ./Container -->
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was indeed using sass!

Comment: No problem! If you found this helpful, feel free to accept the answer with the checkmark icon to help future users. :)

Comment: That really helps, but when I start coding and creating other things in the body, the background image stay fixed, but the overlay scrolls up. That was another thing I was trying to fix with my previous example. Any ideas?

Comment: @PriscillaRisant Ha - I actually caught and fixed that a few minutes ago, but you probably saw an earlier revision of the code. I put `position: fixed` on the gradient to fix that. I updated my example to make the container element tall, so you can see how it looks with scrolling.

Comment: Exactly what I thought! Thank you for helping out :)

Comment: How far back is support for this, though? Mind that over here we are still required to support IE8, although it doesn't have to have the same pretty factor...

Comment: @DavidDylan rgba is supported in IE9+, so this method wouldn't work in IE8. I'm curious, what kind of company still needs to support IE8? Global market share is under 0.4% and I virtually never see people using it in Google Analytics on sites I've worked on.

Comment: It's an accessibility requirement. So, over here it's effectively law depending on type of website. Many people who use assistive tech. are stuck with lower versions because they only get money to upgrade every x years.

Comment: @DavidDylan Ah, cool - understood. Working at creative agencies in the US, I've become thankful for policies like supporting the last 3 versions of major browsers. At this point I hardly worry about IE10, let alone 8 or 9 - though things are very different in the entertainment industry!

Comment: AFAIK; the law is even stricter in the US, although which version to support is really a local choice. But I'd look it up. :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use rgba for the background gradient rather than opacity. Opacity will make every element within the body inherit that opacity.

As you're going to the bottom right in your example, I rotated the gradient by 135 deg in my example below..

I would also suggest you apply a `position:relative` to the container as the gradient will overlay any content within the body. Unless that's the desired effect?

```css
.image-bg {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: url('http://lorempixel.com/output/nature-q-c-1313-1259-2.jpg') center center no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-attachment: fixed;
}
.image-bg:before {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, rgba(226, 220, 225, 0.37) 0%, rgba(232, 213, 228, 1) 100%);
}
.container {
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<body class="image-bg">
  <div class="container" id="main">

    <div class="logo">
      <h1>Background Overlay Image</h1>
    </div>
    <!-- ./ logo -->

  </div>
  <!-- ./Container -->
```